# Typescript Map doesn't receive entries from set()

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

i am trying to use a `Map` to store some data in a class. On creation I am initializing the `Map` with initial data. The Problem is that after the `initBoard()` function the `Map` is still empty.

The `Map` which makes the problem is located inside the `Scoreboard` class. During the `initBoard()` the `Map` should be filled with the player names as a key and the value should be an array of `ScoreEntry`. The problem is that the `Map` stays empty.

A minimal working sample:

player.ts

```js
import { log } from './index';

export class Player {
    private id: string;

    constructor(inID: string) {
        this.id = inID;
    }

    getID(): string {
        log.silly(`[Player (${this.id})] Returning ID.`);
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

scoreboard.ts

```js
import { log } from '.';
import { Player } from './player';

export class Scoreboard {
    private players: Array<Player>;
    private board: Map<string, Array<ScoreEntry>>;

    constructor(plrs: Array<Player>) {
        this.players = plrs;
        this.board = new Map<string, Array<ScoreEntry>>();
        this.initBoard();
    }

    initBoard(): void {
        log.info(`[ScoreBoard] Initializing.`);

        const max = this.getMaxRoundNumber();
        log.debug(`[ScoreBoard] Maximum Rounds: ${max}.`);

        this.players.forEach((player: Player) => {
            let temp = new Array<ScoreEntry>(max);
            for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                temp[i] = new ScoreEntry();
            }
            this.board.set(player.getID(), temp);
        });
    }

    getMaxRoundNumber(): number {
        switch (this.players.length) {
            case 3:
                return 20;
            case 4:
                return 15;
            case 5:
                return 12;
            case 6:
                return 10;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
class ScoreEntry {
    private target!: number;
    private score: number;

    constructor() {
        this.score = 0;
    }

    getScore(): number {
        return this.score;
    }

    getTarget(): number {
        return this.target;
    }

    setScore(val: number) {
        this.score = val;
    }

    setTarget(val: number) {
        this.target = val;
    }
}
```

index.ts

```js
import { Logger, TLogLevelName } from 'tslog';
import { Player } from './player';
import { Scoreboard } from './scoreboard';

const loglevel = process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'silly';

export const log: Logger = new Logger({
    name: 'min_example',
    minLevel: loglevel as TLogLevelName,
    dateTimeTimezone: 'Europe/Berlin',
});

const a = new Player('a')
const b = new Player('b')
const c = new Player('c')

const players = [a, b, c]

const scoreboard = new Scoreboard(players)

console.log(JSON.stringify(scoreboard))
log.debug(`Board`, scoreboard)
```

Thoses classes ran with node and TypeScript compiler targeted at `ES2020` produce the following output for me: I used my logger for the project as well as `console.log` to show that it isn't a problem with the logger.

```
2021-06-14 15:10:53.302 INFO [wizard_backend build/scoreboard.js:12  Scoreboard.initBoard] [ScoreBoard] Initializing. 
2021-06-14 15:10:53.306 DEBUG [wizard_backend build/scoreboard.js:14  Scoreboard.initBoard] [ScoreBoard] Maximum Rounds: 20. 
2021-06-14 15:10:53.306 SILLY [wizard_backend build/player.js:10  Player.getID] [Player (a)] Returning ID. 
2021-06-14 15:10:53.308 SILLY [wizard_backend build/player.js:10  Player.getID] [Player (b)] Returning ID. 
2021-06-14 15:10:53.308 SILLY [wizard_backend build/player.js:10  Player.getID] [Player (c)] Returning ID. 
{"players":[{"id":"a"},{"id":"b"},{"id":"c"}],"board":{}}
2021-06-14 15:10:53.310 DEBUG [wizard_backend build/index.js:22 Object.<anonymous>] Board 
Scoreboard {
  players: [
    Player {
      id: 'a'
    },
    Player {
      id: 'b'
    },
    Player {
      id: 'c'
    }
  ],
  board: Map {}
}
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(mapObject)` returns `{}`. You can check the duplicate for some alternatives.

Comment: You can use `console.log(Array.from(scoreboard.board))` to check whether the `Map` is populated or not

Comment: Okay that shows that the map is populated. But i need to transfer this map via a REST API which means i need to use a JSON.stringify with replacer an reviver because express cant parse it ? (That is the real problem) with res.json()

Comment: If it has string or number keys, you need to convert it to an an object. Or use an array of entries `[ [key,value], [key,value] ]` using `Array.from()`. Maps can have objects as keys. There's no way to represent that in JSON format.